# Catch statement does not catch thrown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, try-catch

For some reason this code gives me an uncaught exception error. It seems the catch block is not catching the error. Are try catch blocks scoped in such a way that I cannot throw an error in a nested function, and then expect it to be caught by a catch statement scoped higher up the chain? Some of the sensitive data with in the application that i'm working in has been removed, but it expected that leadInfo[ 0 / 1] would be a 32 character alpha numeric string that I pull from URL parameters.

The underlying issue here is with my AJAX call returning an error from the API and that error not being handled properly within the application. Hence the need for the throw statement. The AJAX call completes fine, and returns a JSON object that does not contain the email address as a property, so I need to handle that in a way that changes the page to reflect that.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        try {
            url = "http://api.com/api/v1/lead/" + leadInfo[1]

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: url,
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                success: function (result) {

                    result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

                    if(!result.data.email){
                        throw ('New exception');
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                    jQuery('.email').html(result.data.email);
                }
            });


            jQuery('.surveryButton').click(function(){
                window.location.replace("http://" + pgInventory.host + pgInventory.path + leadInfo[0] + "&curLeadId=" + leadInfo[1] + "&curViewedPages=0");
            });
        }
        catch(err) {
            jQuery('.email').html('your e-mail address');
            jQuery('#arrowContent').remove();
        }
});
```

Comment: could you also be throwing another error in the catch block? I found out this was what I was doing.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The reason why your `try catch` block is failing is because an ajax request is asynchronous. The try catch block will execute before the Ajax call and send the request itself, but the error is thrown when the result is returned, AT A LATER POINT IN TIME.

When the `try catch` block is executed, there is no error. When the error is thrown, there is no `try catch`. If you need `try catch` for ajax requests, always put ajax `try catch` blocks inside the `success` callback, NEVER outside of it.

Here's how you should do it:

```
success: function (result) {
    try {
      result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

      if (!result.data.email) {
         throw ('New exception');
      }
      console.log(result);
      jQuery('.email').html(result.data.email);
    } catch (exception) {
      console.error("bla");
    };
}
```

Comment: It looks like I had my understanding of JSONP calls a bit backwards. I was under the impression that JSONP calls were always forced to be synchronous, turns out its exactly the opposite, they are always forced to be asynchronous. This makes complete sense now that that little bit of information has been resolved. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Note that awaiting the promise where the error is thrown will bubble up the error as expected

Comment: thanks mate, going to note this one that throwing error on an async function is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

Due to the asynchronous nature of the callback methods in javascript, the context of the function throwing the error is different compared to the original one. You should do this way:

```
success: function (result) {
  try {
    result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    if(!result.data.email){
      throw ('New exception');
    }
    console.log(result);
    jQuery('.email').html(result.data.email);
  }
  catch(err) {
    // Dealing with the error
  }
}
```

I would suggest you to have a look at this excellent [article](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations) about the (very particular) **contexts**, **closures** and **bindings** in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ajax is asynchronous by definition. Your exception does not get thrown from within the `$.ajax` function, but from the **callback** function on success (which is triggered at a later time).

You should give an `error: function(data) {}` parameter to it as well, to handle server response errors, and furthermore you should place the try/catch block **inside** the callback function.

If you really want to catch it outside the callback, then you should consider calling a function rather than throwing an exception, because I don't see how it can be done.