# aws cdk SSM parameter not available in account

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, aws-ssm

i have a code that reads a value from SSM parameter which is going to be built in codebuild project. For the first time ever run, the value will not exist yet, so i wrote a logic that will catch the error and it is supposed to continue, but even with the logic, i'm still getting

```
SSM parameter not available in account 1234, region us-east-1: /api-endpoint error stops the codebuild project error
```

below is the code

```
let apiEndpoint: string;

    try {
      apiEndpoint = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, `api-endpoint`)
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.message.includes('ParameterNotFound')) {
        // Handle the case where the parameter doesn't exist yet
        console.warn('SSM parameter "api-endpoint" not found. Using default value.');
        apiEndpoint = 'default-value';
      } else {
        // Handle other errors
        throw error;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR  You can't catch the error this way.  Perhaps you could create the parameter in the CDK with a dummy value, then have the CodeBuild project update its value.

#### Why isn't the catch block handling the error?

The catch block won't catch the `SSM parameter not available` error.  It wouldn't handle it even if the error message did contain the text `ParameterNotFound`.  This is because, under the hood, the `valueFromLookup` method is a so-called [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html). It makes an async SDK [GetParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html) call to fetch the parameter from AWS and caches the result.

Because of this async call, your try-catch block exits before `valueFromLookup` finishes.  See the SO questions [Catch statement does not catch thrown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316815/catch-statement-does-not-catch-thrown-error) and [Why is try {} .. catch() not working with async/await function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102365/why-is-try-catch-not-working-with-async-await-function) for explanations.

You can demonstrate this to yourself by adding a log command below your code:

```js
console.log("after try/catch - will get logged before the error message!");
```

The following will get logged to the console when you `cdk synth`:

```
after try/catch - will get logged before the error message!
after try/catch - will get logged before the error message!
[Error at MyStack] SSM parameter not available in account 1234, region us-east-1: /api-endpoint
```

(The log message gets logged twice because of the way context fetching is implemented)

Answer (score 0):

this cannot work.
Note that the line `ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(this, 'api-endpoint')`  does not need the `await` statement. This is because this line does not actually execute any requests to AWS to validate if the parameter exists. For this reason it does not actually throw any errors. Your CDK process only builds a CloudFormation template that inserts contains a reference to this parameter. Then the actual error comes from a whole separate process that is completely outside of your control.

If you want to import an SSM value on your stack, the value must exist beforehand. One way to achieve this could be to create a whole separate stack that initializes the parameter so that then you can import it here.

Comment: `valueFromLookup` does make an initial cloud-side call, then caches the result.  It's a so-called [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) that _"Gets a value from the current Region's Amazon EC2 Systems Manager Parameter Store."_

Comment: Lets say that i have CDN stack and API stack, the CDN stack needs to import API endpoint using SSM lookup that is created in API stack (API stack creates SSM parameter with the value of API endpoint). If i deploy these stacks for the very first time, the SSM parameter has not yet created, that is where this problem comes in the CodeBuild project that says `SSM parameter not available`. That is why i was trying to add a default value because first time run wouldnt have the SSM yet , what would be the solution to this? @fedonev @KamilJanowski

Comment: @fedoenv note that your deployment goes through phases. Your CDK code is executed as part of the synthesis phase. Try killing your wifi and executing 'cdk synth'. it will still work, because synth does not need any internet connection because it does not execute any calls. What you'll find however is that the actual synthesised template will contain a parameter of type `AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>`. That will be resolved during the actual deployment phase - long after the your TS code was executed. This is why this try-catch can never catch this thing

Comment: @JackRogers You have then a clear dependency of one stack over another. You have to deploy them in order. The api stack goes first. Note that the resolution of your SSM parameter is done at the deployment time only. The CDN will not look up the SSM after it is deployed. The SSM-approach in CF/CDK is introduced not to introduce the values lazily, but to introduce "soft dependencies" - the alternative to using stack output exports, which will prevent you from making certain updates the the API stacks as long as there are any other stacks depending on your outputs